# How to increase lines in a report on Salesforce

Tags: dashboard, custom-reports

So guys, I got a field 'action plan' that is getting cut when it reaches a certain number of letters in this report, check this out:

[image: as you can see, the max is 1500...]

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I cannot solve this lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot display more than 255 characters of a long text field in a Salesforce report for performance reasons. [There is a pending idea to increase this limit.](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdlv2UAB/more-than-255-characters-in-a-long-text-area-custom-field-is-not-visible-in-the)

If you need that data you can try exporting the report in the report interface, using Dataloader, or an API.